# Elasticsearch search query: nested query with OR-gates & AND-gates

Tags: elasticsearch

I have docs as follow:
{
"name": "...",
"country": "...",
}

I need to find. either one of the following criteria:

- name=John AND country=US
- name=Andy AND country=UK

How should be write this nested query?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the default fields mapping is defined, you can use [boolean queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as follows:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "name.keyword": "John"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "country.keyword": "US"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "name.keyword": "Andy"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "country.keyword": "UK"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You should use `must` instead of `filter` if you want the query to contribute to the score.

**must**

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will
> contribute to the score.

**filter**

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike
> must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
> executed in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch//reference/current/query-filter-context.html), meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching.

Comment: What if I replace "filter" with "must"?

Comment: I've updated my answer.